# Spring Data Rest PUT v.s PATCH LinkableResources

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Data REST to expose my Entity's and their relationships. I have a OneToOne relationship between two Entity's and I'm trying to update/change the relationship with PUT and PATCH.

I noticed that Spring Data REST will only allow you to update linked resources - *JPA mapped Entity's (OneToMany, ManyToOne, etc) which are also AggregateRoots (has a Repository)* - via a **PATCH** and are ignored with a  **PUT**.

This can be seen in the [LinkedAssociationSkippingAssociationHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/DomainObjectReader.java#L569) class:

```
if (associationLinks.isLinkableAssociation(association)) {
  return;
}
```

Why is this? What is the reasoning behind this?

Is it because the design wants us to treat the associations as resources themselves as seen in [this part of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource)? I can alter the relationship via a PUT with Content-Type text/uri-list but it feels unnatural and require an additional HTTP request.

Answer (score 6):

From the Spring data REST 2.5.9.RELEASE the associations are not update on PUT request and only update using PATCH.

**[Changes in version 2.5.9.RELEASE (2017-04-19)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/changelog.txt)**

[DATAREST-1030 - PATCH requests do not handle links to associations properly.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/359513fe9bdcd679f1ff0b1154d65b973201b800#diff-63e4af7a7a88565be2f1494ede2de7ab)

Other links about this:

[DATAREST-1061: PUT-request with application/json media type payload cannot update association @OneToOne by URI](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1061)

[Domain Driven Design and Spring](https://github.com/olivergierke/lectures/blob/master/ddd-and-spring/index.adoc#domain-driven-design-and-spring)

Comment: You just confirmed the fact while we still don't understand why PATCH and POST are properly resolve associations but PUT skips them. Anybody can explain it in English?